# Linux trigger on a command

Tags: linux, event-log

I would like to listening on a command.

So my idea is that either systerm or human call a command log it somewhere with the given parameters.

Can i solve it somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Auditd and `auditctl` will probably meet your needs.